# Bluemix SQLDB Query - Can't figure out JSON Parameter Markings

Tags: sql, json, db2, ibm-cloud, node-red

In my Nodered Bluemix application, I'm trying to make a SqlDB query, but I can't find sufficient documentation or examples on how to use the parameter markings in the query. Are there any examples and further insight into what I am doing wrong? Here is the flow I am having trouble with:

```
[
    {       
        "id":"7924a83a.03355",
        "type":"websocket-listener",
        "path":"/ws/dbdata",
        "wholemsg":"false"
    },
    {
        "id":"b84efad2.9a2a58",
        "type":"function",
        "name":"Parse JSON",
        "func":"msg.payload = JSON.parse(msg.payload);\nvar begin = msg.payload[0].split(\" \");\nbegin[1] = begin[1]+\":00\";\nvar date1 = begin[0].split(\"-\");\nvar processStart = date1[2]+\"-\"+date1[0]+\"-\"+date1[1]+\" \"+begin[1];\n\nvar end = msg.payload[0].split(\" \");\nend[1] = end[1]+\":00\";\nvar date2 = end[0].split(\"-\");\nvar processEnd = date2[2]+\"-\"+date2[0]+\"-\"+date2[1]+\" \"+end[1];\n\nmsg.payload[0] = processStart;\nmsg.payload[1] = processEnd;\nreturn msg;",
        "outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":381.79998779296875,"y":164.8000030517578,"z":"3f9da5d2.b3f0aa",
        "wires":[["4f92b16a.cf981"]]
    },
    {
        "id":"3e20f8a4.06451",
        "type":"websocket in",
        "name":"dbInput",
        "server":"7924a83a.03355",
        "client":"",
        "x":159.8000030517578,"y":164.8000030517578,"z":"3f9da5d2.b3f0aa",
        "wires":[["b84efad2.9a2a58"]]
    },
    {
        "id":"68a4a35.5983f5c",
        "type":"debug",
        "name":"",
        "active":true,"console":"false",
        "complete":"true",
        "x":970.7999877929688,"y":162.8000030517578,"z":"3f9da5d2.b3f0aa",
        "wires":[]
    },
    {
        "id":"5a0aed1c.34279c",
        "type":"sqldb in",
        "service":"LabSensors-sqldb",
        "query":"",
        "params":"{msg.begin},{msg.end}",
        "name":"db Request",
        "x":787.7999877929688,"y":163.8000030517578,"z":"3f9da5d2.b3f0aa",
        "wires":[["68a4a35.5983f5c"]]
    },
    {
        "id":"e08c4a85.e95e68",
        "type":"debug",
        "name":"",
        "active":true,"console":"false",
        "complete":"true",
        "x":791.7999877929688,"y":233.8000030517578,"z":"3f9da5d2.b3f0aa",
        "wires":[]
    },
    {
        "id":"4f92b16a.cf981",
        "type":"function",
        "name":"Construct Query",
        "func":"msg.begin = msg.payload[0];\nmsg.end = msg.payload[1];\nmsg.payload = \"SELECT * FROM IOT WHERE TIME >= '?' AND TIME < '?'\";\nreturn msg;",
        "outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":583.7999877929688,"y":163.8000030517578,"z":"3f9da5d2.b3f0aa",
        "wires":[["5a0aed1c.34279c",
        "e08c4a85.e95e68"]]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the node-red documentation for the SQLDB query node it says:

"**Parameter Markers** is a comma delimited set of json paths. These will replace any question marks that you place in your query, in the order that they appear."

Have you tried removing the curly braces, i.e. to set the "params" field in the node to just "msg.begin,msg.end"?

Comment: When I put "msg.begin,msg.end" the sqldb node no longer gives me an error, but the query does not give me any result. I know that this query should return some values because when I hardcode the query it works. Did I format the msg.payload correctly? `msg.payload = "SELECT * FROM IOT WHERE TIME >= '?' AND TIME < '?'";`

Comment: Going off of that, changing the payload to `msg.payload = "SELECT * FROM IOT WHERE TIME >= "+"?"+" AND TIME < "+"?";` seemingly produces a valid query, but my debug node is outputting this `{ "payload": [], "_session": { "type": "websocket", "id": "fcc17050.033e9" }, "_msgid": "1918d7ee.e6e728", "begin": "2015-08-07 15:30:00", "end": "2015-08-07 15:30:00" }` - an empty result.

Comment: The last msg.payload format worked once I corrected a logic error I found elsewhere in my flow.

Answer (score 0):

You just need remove single quotes this is a correct sentence:

msg.payload = "SELECT * FROM IOT WHERE TIME >= ? AND TIME < ?";